How to get Classic Pivot Table Layout generated in EPPlus to work properly "out of the box"?
I have the beginnings of VERY rudimentary Pivot Table built with EPPlus.  I am trying to get "Classic Pivot Table Layout" to work properly.
Here is the simple code that creates the data source and the pivot sheet:
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable;

namespace EppTrial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] workbookBytes;
            using (var p = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var sheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DataSheet");

                var filledRange = sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(GetDataTable(), true, TableStyles.Dark1);

                sheet.Cells["E"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "d MMM";

                filledRange.AutoFitColumns();


                var pivotSheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PivotSheet");

                var pivotTable = pivotSheet.PivotTables.Add(pivotSheet.Cells["A3"], filledRange, "ThePivotTableName");

                pivotTable.ColumnGrandTotals = true;
                pivotTable.Compact = false;
                pivotTable.CompactData = false;
                pivotTable.DataCaption = "Values";
                pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;
                pivotTable.ErrorCaption = "[error]";
                pivotTable.GridDropZones = true;
                pivotTable.Outline = false;
                pivotTable.OutlineData = false;
                pivotTable.RowGrandTotals = true;
                pivotTable.ShowColumnHeaders = true;
                pivotTable.ShowError = true;
                pivotTable.ShowHeaders = true;
                pivotTable.ShowMemberPropertyTips = false;
                pivotTable.ShowValuesRow = false;

                foreach (string fieldName in new []{ "R1-Res", "R2-Proj" })
                {
                    var field = pivotTable.Fields[fieldName];
                    field.Outline = false;
                    field.Compact = false;
                    field.SubTotalFunctions = eSubTotalFunctions.None;
                    field = pivotTable.RowFields.Add(field);
                    field.ShowDropDowns = true;
                    field.Items.Refresh();
                }

                workbookBytes = p.GetAsByteArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\EPP\trial.xlsx", workbookBytes);
        }

        public static DataTable GetDataTable()
        {
            // Named Table
            var table = new DataTable("DataTable");

            // Columns
            table.Columns.Add("F1-Client", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("F2-Eng", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("R1-Res", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("R2-Proj", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("C1-Date", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("C2-Type", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("V1-Hours", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("V2-Rev", typeof(double));

            // Rows
            table.Rows.Add("GM", "Design", "Joe", "Buick", new DateTime(2024, 9, 1), "Act", 8, 100);
            table.Rows.Add("GM", "Design", "Joe", "Buick", new DateTime(2024, 10, 1), "Act", 6, 80);
            table.Rows.Add("GM", "Design", "Mary", "Buick", new DateTime(2024, 9, 2), "Act", 4, 50);
            table.Rows.Add("GM", "Design", "Mary", "Buick", new DateTime(2024, 10, 2), "Act", 6, 75);
            table.Rows.Add("GM", "Design", "Joe", "Chevy", new DateTime(2024, 9, 2), "Act", 7, 90);
            table.Rows.Add("GM", "Design", "Mary", "Chevy", new DateTime(2024, 10, 3), "Act", 4, 40);
            table.Rows.Add("GM", "Build", "Joe", "Chevy", new DateTime(2024, 8, 1), "Act", 10, 200);
            table.Rows.Add("Ford", "Build", "Mary", "Ranger", new DateTime(2024, 8, 2), "Act", 10, 250);
            table.Rows.Add("Ford", "Design", "Joe", "Ranger", new DateTime(2024, 7, 1), "Act", 5, 150);

            return table;
        }
    }
}


When I open the resulting file in Excel and go to the PivotSheet sheet, I see the following:

Note the incorrect label in A4 and the missing drop-down widget in B4.
Now in Excel, I can view the Display tab of the Pivot Table options - screen shot follows:

If I now uncheck the selected "Classic Pivot Table Layout" option and hit OK to save the changes, and then re-open the same Display tab of the Pivot Table options and reselect the very same option "Classic Pivot Table Layout" that I had just previously unchecked, now the pivot table looks and behaves correctly:

Any suggestions as to how I can modify my code so that this portion of the Pivot Table renders correctly both the correct row-field column label and the correct (working) dropdown widget?
